# Using a reference to an anonymous array as an element of an array

Tags: perl

I am trying to use a reference to an array in various ways that I understand can be done. 
Here's one of my trial: -

```
my $RoR = [[2, 3], [4, 5, 7]];
my @AoA = ([2, 3], [[2, 3], [4, 5, 7]]);
my @AwR = ([2, 3], @{$RoR});

print $AoA[1][1][1], "\n";      # 1
print $AoA[1]->[1][1], "\n";    # 2

#print $RoR[0][1], "\n";        # 3
print $RoR->[0][1], "\n";       # 4

print $AwR[1][1][1], "\n";          # 5
print $AwR[1]->[1][1], "\n";        # 6
```

As you can see, I have three different arrays.

- `$RoR` -> Is a reference to an anonymous array, which contains two anonymous arrays
- `@AoA` -> Is an array containing 2 anonymous array. 2nd anonymous array is same as the array pointed to by the reference `$RoR`
- `@AwR` -> Is almost same as `@AoA`, but with a difference that, rather than having a new anonymous array, I have added the reference `@{$RoR}` itself, inside it. So, basically I think, the last two arrays are practically the same.

Now, the problem is, **they are not behaving in the same way**.

- The print statements `1`, and `2` are working fine, and printing out the value `5` as result.
- The print statement `3` is giving error, which I know why, so no problem in it. The print statement `4` is printing the value `3`, as expected.
- Now, the print statement `5` and `6` are throwing some errors when I try to run the program.

  ```
  "Can't use string ("2") as an ARRAY ref while \"strict refs\" in use at 
  D:/_Perl Practice/3perldsc/array_of_array.pl line 15."
  ```

Then I tried using: -

```
print $AwR[1][1]->[1], "\n";    
print @{$RoR}[1]->[1];
```

Where, I replaced `$AwR[1]` with `@{$RoR}`, as `$AwR[1]` contains `@{$RoR}`. The second one is working fine, while the first one is still throwing error.

So, what exactly is the difference between the `1st two` and the `last two` print statements? I thought they are the same, and hence should give same result for same index access. But it is not. Am I using the reference in some wrong way?

---

Ok, now above doubt is clear. So, I have posted an answer accumulating the general stuff related to this question. Please take a look at it below.  In that, I have a doubt in the `5th and 6th` print statement, and to understand it I tried the below test: -

```
print $AwR[1][1];   # Allowed as `$AwR[1]` is same as `$$RoR`.
print $$RoR[1];     # Allowed as in 3(b)
print $AwR[1]->[1]; # Confused here. It is allowed
print $$RoR->[1];   # But this is not.
```

The first three statement are printing the same `reference value`. But the last one is failing. So, its sure that :- `$AwR[1]` is same as `$$RoR`. But, why `$$RoR->[1]` is not working while `$AwR[1]->[1]` is working? It's throwing me this error: -

```
Not a SCALAR reference at D:/_Perl Practice/3perldsc/array_of_array.pl line 24.
```

So, what's the difference in using it in two different way?

Comment: may I recommend the excellent doc [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://p3rl.org/reftut), it really helped me learn these things!

Comment: @JoelBerger. Thanks for that, but I am studying from that only. And I posted this example after understanding from the doc only.. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In assignement to `@AwR` you dereference your reference to anonymous array `$RoR`, so you get basicly this behaviour:

```
my @AwR = ([2, 3], [2, 3], [4, 5, 7]);
```

not expected:

```
my @AwR = ([2, 3], [[2, 3], [4, 5, 7]]);
```

**UPDATE**

If we have multidimensional array (array of arrays, AoA), then every dimension after first has to be a reference. So there is no need to explicitly to use dereferencing arrow, but it is allowed. So, if we have `AoA` as reference, we need to dereference first dimension explicilty and we may do it two ways `$$AoA` or `$AoA->`, but we can't dereference it twice as you noticed (`$$RoR->[1]` in your example).

Any following dimension we may omit dereferencing arrow, when we need address to certain element, so there is two equivalent use:

```
my @AoA = ([2, 3], [ [2, 3], [4, 5, 7, [11, 12, [111, 112] ] ] ], [0]);
print "A: $AoA[1][1][3][2][0] \n";          # == 111
print "B: $AoA[1]->[1]->[3]->[2]->[0] \n";  # == 111
```

or `AoA` as reference

```
my $AoA = [ [2, 3], [ [2, 3], [4, 5, 7, [11, 12, [111, 112] ] ] ], [0] ];
print "A: $$AoA[1][1][3][2][0] \n";           # == 111
print "B: $AoA->[1]->[1]->[3]->[2]->[0] \n";  # == 111
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't know why, when I tried using `$RoR`. I got some error, so I changed to `@{$RoR}`. Then again I tried `$RoR`. And found that, I was getting error because I was accessing it like this: - `print ${$RoR}->[1][1]`. Where I actually thought I am replacing `$AwR[1]` with `$RoR` in `print $AwR[1]->[1][1]`. But I was not. So silly of me. :( Thanks again. :)

Comment: @w.k.. Hello, Can you please take a look at my post again. I have got a doubt and posted it here. I didn't created a new question, because it is related to this only.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are expecting @AoA and @AwR to be identical, they are not.  You can see this with a simple test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

my $RoR = [[2, 3], [4, 5, 7]];
my @AoA = ([2, 3], [[2, 3], [4, 5, 7]]);
my @AwR = ([2, 3], @{$RoR});

is_deeply(\@AwR, \@AoA, 'arrays match');
```

This is because of the way in which you are inserting $RoR into @AwR.  To create an array identical to @AoA create @AwR without dereferencing $RoR:

```
my @newAwR = ([2, 3], $RoR);
```

and test to confirm this is correct:

```
is_deeply(\@newAwR, \@AoA, 'arrays match');
```

Comment: Thanks for that test @nickisfat. Really helpful. Got it now where I went wrong. :)

Comment: @nickisfat.. Hello, Can you please take a look at my post again. I have got a doubt and posted it here. I didn't created a new question, because it is related to this only.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now that I got it somewhat clear, I thought I would post what I have as an answer: -

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

my $RoR = [[2, 3], [4, 5, 7]];
my @AoA = ([2, 3], [[2, 3], [4, 5, 7]], [0]);
my @AwR = ([2, 3], $RoR, [0]);

print "1: ", $AoA[1][1][1], "\n";       # 1
print "2: ", $AoA[1]->[1][1], "\n";     # 2

#print "3(a): ", $RoR[0][1], "\n";      # 3(a) 
print "3(b): ", $$RoR[0][1], "\n";      # 3(b)          
print "4: ", $RoR->[0][1], "\n";        # 4

print "5: ", $AwR[1][0][1], "\n";       # 5
print "6: ", $AwR[1]->[0][1], "\n";     # 6

print "7: ", $AwR[1][1]->[1], "\n";     # 7
print "8: ", @{$RoR}[1]->[1], "\n";     # 8
print "9: ", @{$AwR[1]}[1]->[1], "\n";  # 9
```

**Explanation: -**

- First two print statements are straight forward. They both will print the value `5`
- 3(a) will not compile, as we cannot access index of anonymous array on reference without an `arrow`.
- 3(b) works, because now, we have de-referenced our `reference - $RoR` by using `$$RoR`
- 4th print statement, is similar to the `3(b)`, and is a clear way to do what `3(b)` is doing. Since `RoR` is a reference to an anonymous array, so we can't access the elements like the normal array. We have to use an arrow (`->`). After `arrow` we can add indices to any level to access nested `anonymous` array.

`$$RoR[0][1]` works because, `$RoR` binds more tightly to the de-referencer `$` on the left side, than to the `subscript` operator on the right side. So, first `$RoR` is de-referenced to get the array, and then `subscript` is applied.

Here's a quote from the **Perl Documentation**: -

> Perl's precedence rules on its five prefix
>   dereferencers(which look like someone swearing: $ @ * % &) make them
>   bind more tightly than the postfix subscripting brackets or braces.
>   The seemingly equivalent construct in Perl, $$aref[$i] first does the
>   deref of $aref, making it take $aref as a reference to an array, and
>   then dereference that, and finally tell you the i'th value of the
>   array pointed to by $AoA

- 5th and 6th print statement are similar to 3(b). Since `$AwR[1]` contains the reference `$RoR` only. So, `$AwR[1]` gets converted to: `$$RoR`. Hence, `$AwR[1][0][1]` is similar to `$$RoR[0][1]` in 5th statement. And the 6th statement: - `$AwR[1]->[0][1]` gets converted to: - `$$RoR->[0][1]`. Now here's my doubt. How is `6th` statement working. Why can we use `an arrow` on a `de-referenced reference`.
- In `7th` print statement, `$AwR[1][1]->[1]` is similar to `${$RoR}[1]->[1]`. So, it is clear that de-referencing is done prior to the subscript operator. Hence, we can access the `2nd` element on array obtained after `de-referencing` the reference `$RoR`.
- `8th` and `9th` print statement are pretty same. There also, we are de-referencing the `reference $RoR`. But now, we are `de-referencing` to an `array` rather than a `scalar`.

---

I have tried to explain in the best way I could. If there is something wrong or something missing in the above explanation, then please point that out. That will help me learn more.

Also, can someone please explain the `5th` and `6th` print statement. I'll add this to the question above.